# XSL select distinct child node and get all the parents group by those child

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml that look like this :

```
<texto id="1">
    <user_id>1</user_id>
    ...
</texto>
<texto id="2">
    <user_id>1</user_id>
    ...
</texto>
<texto id="3">
    <user_id>2</user_id>
    ...
</texto>
```

And I would like to transform it to look like this :

```
<user id="1">
    <texto id="1">...</texto>
    <texto id="2">...</texto>
</user>
<user id="2">
    <texto id="3">...</texto>
</user>
```

I try the following xsl:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="user_ids" select="distinct-values(//document/texto/user_id)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$user_ids">
            <xsl:variable name="user_id" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="textos" select="//document/texto[user_id = $user_id]"/>
            <user id="$user_id">

            </user>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

But at this point I get an error : Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item: the context item is not a node

How can I group all texto node by their distinct user child node?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`<xsl:for-each-group select="//texto" group-by="user_id">
<user id="{current-grouping-key()}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
</user>
</xsl:for-each-group>`

then write a template for the texto elements

`<xsl:template match="texto">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*, node() except user_id"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>`